# info guarded by conditional in recipe?

Tags: gnu-make

We have a library project and its transitioning from unaligned data access common in the old i386/i686/x86_64 to aligned data access. The impetus is GCC and vectorization, which is causing crashes at `-O3` (GCC is even vectorizing string compares with SSE4 primitives).

If someone runs make and a particular define is not present, then we want to print a `info` message warning them. I'm having trouble crafting the recipe.

The following recipe produces an error when run (it uses <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and not spaces):

```
.PHONY check_defines
check_defines:
    CONFIG_ALIGNED := $(shell $(EGREP) -i -c "[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]*NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS" config.h)
    CXX_ALIGNED := $(shell echo $(value CXXFLAGS) | $(EGREP) -i -c "-DNO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS")
    ifeq ($(CONFIG_ALIGNED)$(CXX_ALIGNED),00)
        $(info Warning: NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS is not defined)
    endif
```

The error is:

```
$ make check_defines
GNUmakefile:383: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Line 383 is the `CONFIG_ALIGNED := ...`. The manual on [5.1 Recipe Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html) is not really helpful to me.

How do I craft the rule to perform the test within a recipe?

Comment: You might want to allow whitespace between `-D` and `NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS`

Comment: You're missing a colon in the phony target declaration. It should read: `.PHONY: check_defines`. This does trigger a `missing separator` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefiles are not parsed like a script and executed imperatively. A recipe is not a sub-routine.

The page you linked to explicitly tells you that the body of the recipe is treated as shell commands, not make declarations/expressions:

> - A variable definition in a “rule context” which is indented by a tab as the first character on the line, will be considered part of a recipe, not a make variable definition, and passed to the shell.
> - A conditional expression (ifdef, ifeq, etc. see Syntax of Conditionals) in a “rule context” which is indented by a tab as the first character on the line, will be considered part of a recipe and be passed to the shell.

So you can't declare make variables or use make conditionals. You can only use shell commands.

Try something like:

```
CONFIG_ALIGNED := $(shell $(EGREP) -i -c "[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]*NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS" config.h)
CXX_ALIGNED := $(shell echo $(value CXXFLAGS) | $(EGREP) -i -c "-DNO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS")
ifeq ($(CONFIG_ALIGNED)$(CXX_ALIGNED),00)
CHECK_FAILED := 1
endif

.PHONY check_defines
check_defines:
        if [ $(CHECK_FAILED) = 1 ]; then echo Warning: NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS is not defined; exit 1; fi
```

Or check the condition using the shell:

```
CONFIG_ALIGNED := $(shell $(EGREP) -i -c "[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]*NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS" config.h)
CXX_ALIGNED := $(shell echo $(value CXXFLAGS) | $(EGREP) -i -c "-DNO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS")

.PHONY check_defines
check_defines:
        if [ $(CONFIG_ALIGNED)$(CXX_ALIGNED) = 00 ]; then echo Warning: NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS is not defined; exit 1; fi
```

Or do it all with the shell, declaring shell variables instead of make variables:

```
.PHONY check_defines
check_defines:
        config_aligned=`$(EGREP) -i -c "[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]*NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS" config.h`
        cxx_aligned=`echo $(value CXXFLAGS) | $(EGREP) -i -c "-DNO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS")`
        if [ $${config_aligned}$${cxx_aligned} = 00 ]; then echo Warning: NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS is not defined; exit 1; fi
```

(This version might not work if CXXFLAGS contains any shell-outs such as `` `pkg-config --cflags foo` `` as that would confuse the shell)

Comment: Thanks. The last one looks appealing because it avoids the shell unless its needed.

Comment: Please see my other answer. The manual is unfortunately a bit misguiding. First, `ifxxx ... endif` preprocessor-style blocks can be used in recipes, but as they say, they must not have a tab char before them, and they aren't evaluated when the recipe is executed, but when the file is parsed. Secondly, the rest of the syntax is available, like `$(if ...)` expressions, or even `$(eval ...)`

Answer (score 3):

In the recipee, you need to put make's parser out of shell mode with any `$(...)` expression.

```
.PHONY: check_defines
check_defines:
    $(eval CONFIG_ALIGNED := $(shell echo 0))
    $(eval CXX_ALIGNED := $(shell echo 0))
    $(if $(filter 00,$(CONFIG_ALIGNED)$(CXX_ALIGNED)), \
        $(warning Warning: NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS is not defined) \
    )
```

Note that the variables declared are not local to the rule, so you might as well not declare them and put the shell expressions directly in the if expression.